# How can I show that this set is (or not is) a Borel set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose we have two Polish spaces $X$ and $Y$ and two Borel injective functions $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$. Consider the following map $$\Phi: \mathcal P(X)\to \mathcal P(X);\ Z\mapsto X\setminus g(Y\setminus f(Z)).$$ It has a fixed point in $\bigcup\{Z\subseteq X\mid Z\subseteq\Phi(Z)\}\in\mathcal P(X)$; is this set a Borel set of $X$? If it is, how can I show that?

Comment: I believe $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ in the display should be $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: of course yes, sorry...

Comment: No need to apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be proved that the operator $\Phi$ is *continuous*, meaning that the fixpoint can be obtained as the intersection (the “limit”) of the iterates $\Phi^{(n)}(X)$. Since injective Borel maps between Polish spaces send Borel sets to Borel sets, each iterate is Borel and thus the intersection also is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to ask you more; which theorem are you using to saying that the fixed point of $\Phi$ can be obtained as intersection of the iterates?

Comment: You're welcome. If I'm not mistaken, this $\Phi$ is used in one proof of the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem. I recall having seen the statement (only) of continuity, but in this particular application I think it is straightforward, since in particular the iterates are decreasing. That is, you will be able to prove directly that that intersection is the (greatest) fixpoint.

Comment: Yes, you are right; in fact $\Phi$ acts continuously on intersections and this is enough to conclude that $\bigcap\Phi^{(n)}(X)$ is a fixpoint (as you said, the gratest one because the decrease of the function). Thanks again.